# Refresh dataset when applying a filter

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, tdataset

I have an TRxQuery in Delphi 5 (which descends from TQuery) bound to a grid. I'm adding a filter edit box and want to filter the grid as the user types. Is there a way to filter the dataset without closing and reopening the query as this causes an unwanted flicker.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Procedure SetFilter(DS:TDataset;Const Filter:String);
begin
   DS.Filtered := false;
   DS.Filter := Filter;
   DS.Filtered := true;
end;
```

Comment: Doing that does not apply the filter to the bound control.

Comment: Possibly some specific settings on the grid or query. I'll have a play.

Comment: Turns out I was being a monkey. The control wasn't behaving as expected. The code above does indeed affect the dataset though.